# Scipy.optimize.curve_fit gets stuck

Tags: python, scipy

I read in a sine wave from an oscilloscope. There are over 30*10^6 points divided into several thousand segments (5000). I need to fit these data, segment for segment. The problem is that the program gets stuck after fitting some segments. The error I get is

`RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.`

I've checked the data of the segment where the program gets stuck. The data are a sine wave like for all of the other segments. When using `try` and `except` I don't get this error but the program stops executing a few segments after the segment where it gets stuck without the exception handling.

Could anyone explain to me what the problem is and how I can get around it?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import readTrc #package to read data from oscilloscope

ch = 'mydata.trc'

tw, ampl, m = readTrc.readTrc(ch)
l=m['WAVE_ARRAY_COUNT']//m['SUBARRAY_COUNT'] #number of points per segment
tw_re = np.reshape(tw, (m['SUBARRAY_COUNT'], l)) #time
ampl_re = np.reshape(ampl, ((m['SUBARRAY_COUNT']), l)) #amplitude

#find frequency of sinewave
fastfft = np.fft.fft(ampl)
freq_array = np.fft.fftfreq(len(ampl),tw[0]-tw[1])
max_value_index = np.argmax(abs(fastfft[1:]) + 1)
frequency = abs(freq_array[max_value_index])

#fit
def fit(tw, a, f, p, o):
    return a * np.sin(2*np.pi*f*tw + p) + o

guess = (0.1,frequency,np.pi,0.01)

for i in range(m['SUBARRAY_COUNT']):
    params, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit, tw_re[i], ampl_re[i], p0=guess)
    a, f, p, o = params
```

Comment: Such error is majorly due to the inconsistency between the data and the curve function. You can plot them to see whether such a fit is indeed impossible in practice.

Comment: This is one possibility. Or your initial values in `guess` are non-convergent. Or your reshaping lead to a situation, scipy can't handle. Or there are NaN values, scipy algorithm finds distracting. Or...it is simply difficult to say without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My feeling is, that changing the `guess` parameters will resolve this problem. Why don't you take the parameters from the previous segment as start values?

Comment: @liliscent you are right, it does not fit that segment alone even when it is outside the loop. But my data are still a sine function as for any other segment. I fitted the previous sine function and used the fitting parameters to fit the segment where the code gets stuck. The agreement is almost perfect.

Comment: @Piinthesky Using the values refined for the previous segment did the trick! Thanks a million!